# Lenovo T520 can't get Intel 6205 driver to install on Windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, wireless-adapter, intel-centrino

I just installed Windows 7 on a Lenovo T520. According to the specs, the wireless adapter is an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205. I downloaded and attempted to install the drivers for this and the associated software called Intel PROSet/Wireless, but apparently the driver installation failed. In device manager, the WLAN entry is still marked as missing, and the wireless adapter does not show up in the adapter list. When I use the PROSet/Wireless diagnostics tool, there are a series of tests it runs. The first one is labelled "Hardware Test" and it fails with the message "Wireless Hardware is not bound to transport driver". Any idea how to get the wireless adpater drivers to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [ThinkVantage Update tool](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=TVSU-UPDATE)?  This will scan the system and identify the needed driver(s) and has solved issues with Lenovo divers many times for me.

Comment: You're a life-saver! I wish I could upvote this 10 times. I spent over 5 hours yesterday researching and attempting to fix this manually to no avail, and the ThinkVantage update tool did it without issue! Right now I'm on superuser connected to the internet through my brand new wireless connection.